# Scrapy Parse Callback is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a csv full of urls I want to crawl which are in urls-test.csv. I want to open up the csv file and crawl each url (removed from the error below so its not shown) and extract the css element. When I try to run my spider I get the following error:

```
2020-04-30 15:09:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.websiteexamples.com/this-is-fake> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jcsmith427/PycharmProjects/sstksitemaps/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/jcsmsith427/PycharmProjects/sstksitemaps/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: QuoteSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

My spider looks like the following:

**items.py**

```
import scrapy
class SstkscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
contriburl = scrapy.Field()
```

**sstkscrape_spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import SstkscrapeItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'sstkscrape'
allowed_domains = ["shutterstock.com"]
f = open("urls-test.csv")
start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
f.close()

def parse(self, response):
    items = SstkscrapeItem()
    contriburl = response.css(".b_q_e a::attr(href)").extract()
    items['contriburl'] = contriburl
    yield items
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class SstkscrapePipeline:
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file in the start_requests method, and yield the requests directly from there instead of putting them all in a big list to begin with.
You can try the following (untested) approach:

```
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sstkscrape'
    allowed_domains = ["shutterstock.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("urls-test.csv", 'r') as f:
            while True:
                url = f.readline()
                yield scrapy.Request(url.strip(),
                                     callback=self.parse,
                                     dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        items = SstkscrapeItem()
        contriburl = response.css(".b_q_e a::attr(href)").extract()
        items['contriburl'] = contriburl
        yield items
```